# Is it possible to upgrade to the next build of Windows Server insider preview 2019?

Tags: windows-server-2019

The insider preview expires tomorrow and a message dialog suggests to download the next preview build. I checked updates and there are none. Is it not possible to update to the next build or do you have to constantly reinstall clean builds from scratch in the server insider preview?
I'm mid-way through experimenting with federated server and certificate manager and AD and I don't want to start creating a forest all over again just to figure out how to do something.

Comment: The tag 'windows-server-2016' is incorrect. Microsoft tries very hard to distinguish long term servicing channel from semi-annual from preview.  Or whatever they are calling those things this month.   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/semi-annual-channel-overview

Comment: @john i have ltsc of '19 but not enough points to create a new tag

Comment: Done that for you.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm mid-way through experimenting with federated server and certificate manager and AD and I don't want to start creating a forest all over again just to figure out how to do something.

Build and join a new domain controller on whatever the new build of 2019 preview is.

Comment: This won't promote the dc to any of the roles or copy of certificates will it? Good idea, I just don't know enough about how to replicate everything.

Comment: The point of joining is that the database is replicated. You can demote the old one and the new takes over.  If the old doesn't boot, well, now you can test ungraceful role seize...

Answer (score 0):

All server preview builds after [February 2018](https://www.ntweekly.com/2018/02/14/windows-server-insider-preview-build-17093-released-place-os-upgrade/), build 17093 can be upgraded in place using the [downloaded ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewserver) and running setup. Just select keep existing settings and files. Windows 10 preview builds can be installed via the updates section in settings.